# Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I was trying to run an old Laravel project on Wamp and keep getting these errors:

- Laravel 5.7
- Php 7.1
- WampServer 3.3

```
In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client (SQL: select * from informa
  tion_schema.tables where table_schema = razi_oil-db and table_name = languages)


In Connector.php line 70:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client


In Connector.php line 70:

  PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a week of trying, my friend told me to reinstall WampServer 3.3 but with `MySQL version 5.7` and that was it, worked for me, hope works for you too

before that, I tried changing the root password of MySQL, changing the my.ini file and so, but didn't work for me!

Comment: if you had used php 7.4 or newer you would have no prohblem at all, or you can always change the encryption of the passworrd